# The system call exit()

Tags: kernel, process

I have to make some modifications in the system call exit(), but I cannot find its implementation. I think that it calls the kernel method `do_exit()` but I am not sure.

Is there anyone who can say where the implementation of the system call `exit()` is or whether it calls `do_exit()` function or not ?

Comment: You _could_ get the source for `installwatch` (part of the `checkinstall` package), which uses a pre-loaded library to intercept all the system calls, and log the file-related ones. `git clone git://git.debian.org/git/collab-maint/checkinstall.git` and change it to just intercept `exit`

Comment: The fact that the manual page for `exit()` is in §3 of the manual is supposed to be a clue that it is not a system call.  (-: